# Spring Boot REST API - Problems displaying information

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have followed [this tutorial](http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/) to build a REST API with Spring Boot. I've got it running and responding to my calls, but there is a problem with the information it displays. When I ask for an entry, I expect something along the lines of

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "petName",
"photo": "meh",
"status": "Meh"
},
```

But instead I get

```
{
"id": 1,
"photo": "meh",
"status": "Meh"
},
```

and I'm not at all sure why.

RestController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/pet")
class PetRestController {

private final PetRepo petRepo;

@RequestMapping(value="/{petId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
Pet getPet(@PathVariable Long petId) {
    return this.petRepo.findOne(petId);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
List<Pet> getPets() {
    return this.petRepo.findAll();
}

@RequestMapping(value="/delete/{petId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
void deletePet(@PathVariable Long petId) {
    this.petRepo.delete(petId);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
void addPet(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String photo, @RequestParam String status) {
    Pet pet = new Pet(name, photo, status);
    this.petRepo.save(pet);
}

@Autowired
PetRestController(PetRepo petRepo){
    this.petRepo = petRepo;
}
}
```

Pet.java

```
@Entity
public class Pet {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getPhoto() {
    return photo;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

@JsonIgnore
public String name;
public String photo;
public String status;

public Pet(String name, String photo, String status) {
    this.name = name;
    this.photo = photo;
    this.status = status;
}

Pet() {

}
}
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an annotation telling Spring **not** to serialize `name` to JSON. Remove the annotation,

```
// @JsonIgnore // <-- remove this.
public String name;
```

Comment: Whoops, missed that one. Thanks. Works now